# Selenium FirefoxDriver returns wrong Text value from element

Tags: selenium, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have following HTML structure:

```
<label for="corp_type_label" id="Type_label">
    <div class="ms-crm-div-NotVisible">Type</div>
    --
    <div class="ms-crm-Inline-GradientMask"></div>
</label>
```

When I try to get label text by Chrome driver by following CSS selector `By.CssSelector("#Type_label")` I get `--` value as expected.

But if I use the same selector and use FirefoxDriver it returns `Type\r\n--`.

FirefoxDriver:

```
WebDriverManager.Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#Type_label")).Text;  
"Type\r\n--"
```

ChromeDriver:

```
WebDriverManager.Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#Type_label")).Text;  
"--"
```

I use ChromeDriver 2.33 and GeckoDriver 0.18.

Why the same selector returns different values from the same HTML?

*Update: Description is updated to simplify the definition of issue.*

Comment: The HTML structure for Firefox was slightly different for Firefox than in Chrome.
Question should be closed as obsolete

Answer (score 1):

Using following XPath I am getting your element. Can you please check the following code?

```
WebDriverManager.Driver.FindElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Type_label']")).Text();
```

Comment: The problem is not in selector actually.
The issue is in Text property of IWebElement.
Text property of the same element returns different values in different browsers.